# NextJS with redux running like as expected but it give warning Text content did not match

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, session-storage

I am following example code redux toolkit  (counter) with NextJS and trying store state to sessionStorage, it's running as expected but the console give warning
`"Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "25"`

It is my redux store :

```
import counterReducer from "./counterSlice";

const initValue = () => {
  let value = 0;
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("counter")) {
      value = sessionStorage.getItem("counter");
    }
  }
  return parseInt(value);
};

const preloadedState = {
  counter: {
    value: initValue(),
  },
};

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
  preloadedState,
});
```

and it is my Page Code :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import useSWR from "swr";

import {
  decrement,
  increment,
  incrementByAmount,
  incrementAsync,
  selectCount,
} from "../redux/counterSlice";

export default function Counter() {
  let count = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div
        style={{ display: "grid", placeContent: "center", textAlign: "center" }}
      >
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <div style={{ display: "grid", gridAutoFlow: "column", gap: 50 }}>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment())}>Inc</button>
          <h4>{count}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>Dec</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Anybody have solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

While you are checking if `window` object exists ( if not, you are running on the server). The problem is that `server` rendered value is `0` while the browser rendered value is `25`. This is happening because the value is immediately calculated in the browser to be `25` (first render in the browser).

You will need to change your code to defer the calculation until the mounting of the component, so the initial `browser` value can also be `0` and than use `useEffect`, which only runs in the browser, to calculate new value.